# Specify namespace/class in VS2019 Test Explorer while using CTest/CMake

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2019

I'm using CMake + VS2019. In my test definition I have something like:

```
add_test(NAME "common/base64" COMMAND my_unit_test "common/base64")
```

VS2019 displays this like:

[image]

In project I have hundreds of tests and it is very inconvenient to search through unclear randomly generated names, expanding each items. So my questions:

- How can I specify recognizable test name (instead of EBF.Tests.52488745200006951440) ?
- How to specify namespace / class?

Also I can see Vs2019 Test Explorer can group by "Traits" - may be I can specify it over this feature?

Comment: Is this an MSVC bug? Is there an open issue for this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the "EBF.Tests" prefix is the "project name".

You can disable the test prefix or set a new one by altering the TEST_PREFIX setting in your test autodiscovery method or the test naming itself.

For CTest, by altering the test naming:

```
# use [namespace].[class].[testname] naming 
add_test("lib.namespace.Tests.SomeTest" test_exe)
```

For Catch2, by altering the test name prefixing by changing TEST_PREFIX in the auto-discovery method:

```
catch_discover_tests(
    TagTestsTarget
    TEST_SPEC "[tag]"                   # select tests by tag name
    TEST_PREFIX "lib.namespace.Tests."  # last dot required !
)
```

Comment: Just have tried your answer. Situation little bit improved, but at top level it still the same (see result there https://imgur.com/Fe8DefF) I can see tree is little bit fixed, but labeling on the top is still `EBF.Tests.5249263290790805005.ABC.OP.namespace.Tests.SomeTest.18840`

Answer (score 0):

### Fast Solution:

Set the **Group By** option in the **Test Explorer** to visualize by `Class`.

Then name each test in your CMake files as: `mytestname.mytestname`

As an example: `add_test(NAME mytest.mytest COMMAND mytest)`

(Not a perfect solution but it works well enough.)

### More details:

When naming tests for the Team Explorer, if there is one dot between the name, will be interpreted as `class name` then `function name`. If there are two dots it will be interpreted as `namespace`, `class`, `function`. Any more dots are appended in the function string.

You could also display on the Team Explorer by `namespace` and then use these naming features to group your tests in at most two levels of hierarchy.

As example you could name all the tests related to a given feature with the same `class` or `namespace` and they will display nicely in the same set in the Team Explorer window.